# Reason behind fight between Gods in Hinduism

Tags: shiva, vishnu, durga

Why there are many stories where one GOD is fighting with another god, I watch a youtube video where Lord Hanumana is Fighting with Lord SHIVA, also, lord shiva fight with Vishnu. Why a god needs to fight with another god, does this represent the fight of good thoughts inside our mind, i.e. when one good thought contradicts with other good thoughts...like the benefit of the nation or benefit of the entire society?

EDIT 1: As per wikash request... I have deleted my 2nd question

Comment: Pls ask 1 q at a time. Voting to close.

Comment: okay as you wish